# brand new app I'm pushing to github

Tags: git, github

```
C:\Dropbox\Apps\rails_projects\ABCD>git push -u origin master
ssh: github: no address associated with name
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

/shrug.  I've done this a dozen times.  Not sure what happened here.  I can push on other apps.  What's unique, here...

other app that's working:

```
C:\Dropbox\Apps\rails_projects\ecorebox>git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:ecorebox.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:ecorebox.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/Mallanaga/ecorebox.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Mallanaga/ecorebox.git (push)
```

new app, not working:

```
C:\Dropbox\Apps\rails_projects\ABCD>git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@github/Mallanaga/ABCD.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@github/Mallanaga/ABCD.git (push)
```

not sure why this new app is insisting on ssh.  is that a new thing?

Comment: Do you have your `user.email` and `user.name` set? What's the output of `git remote -v`? Are you using an encrypted ssh private key that you need to enter a passphrase for?

Comment: updated question. might be an SSH issue?  I have no idea how to handle it, though =/

Comment: How did you clone your new app? What were the exact commands? Also, do you have ssh set up for GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your origin remote URL. It's `github.com`, not `github`.

First, remove your bad remote:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Then add it back with the correct address:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com/Mallanaga/ABCD.git
```

After, you should be able to run `git push -u origin master` without any trouble.

Comment: yup.  I like the rm command too.  I actually just opened up the `config` file in `ABCD\.git`.  I definitely typo'd when I was doing my `git remote add origin https://github.com/Mallanaga/ABCD.git` command.  Some other help said to use SSH.  bleh.  Switched it back to HTML.  All is well =D

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ssh://git@github.com/Mallanaga/ABCD.git
```

instead of

```
ssh://git@github/Mallanaga/ABCD.git
```

The command is

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/Mallanaga/ABCD.git
```